# In tensorflow 2. what becomes a part of the graph and what does not?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

In the code:

```
@tf.function
def f(x):
    print("Python execution: ", x)
    out = x+5.
    tf.print("Graph execution: ", x)
    return out
```

python print executes only during the first invocation of the function i.e. during the graph creation. `out=x+5.` becomes a part of the graph and thus gets executed every time the graph is run. I wanted to know when i write a function in normal python and decorate it with `tf.function` to graph it up, what all gets converted to graph (like `out = x+5`) and what does not (like python print)

Comment: See the "Key point" note in the documentation of [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function): "Any Python side-effects (appending to a list, printing with `print`, etc) will only happen once, when `func` is traced. To have side-effects executed into your [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) they need to be written as TF ops". Essentially, only TensorFlow operations (i.e. TensorFlow function calls and operations involving tensors, like `x+5.`) become part of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating jdehesa's comment for the benefit of the community.

In the Official Documentation for [tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function), it is mentioned as:

> **Key Point**: Any Python side-effects (appending to a list, printing with
>   print, etc) will only happen once, when func is traced. To have
>   side-effects executed into your tf.function they need to be written as
>   **TF ops**:

Applying that explanation to your example, the Operations, `out = x+5` and    `tf.print` will be stored in the `Graph` and the operation `print` doesn't.

It is always recommended to pass `Tensors` as arguments to the functions instead of `Python Scalars` so that all the operations will be captured in a Single Graph.

`tf.function` only allows creating new `tf.Variable` objects when it is called for the first time.

In general, it is recommended to create stateful objects like `tf.Variable` outside of `tf.function` and passing them as arguments.

If we use Python `Assignment` Operator, `a = b`, will not be part of the Graph and `tf.assign` will be. Python `Print` will not be part of the Graph but `tf.Print` will be.

Also, if we want even Python Code to be part of Graph, we can use `tf.py_function` inside our function, but it is not recommended.

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!!

Comment: thank you for the answer. 1. I now also think thta numpy arrays can be sent as an input to graph and they will behave exactly as if they were tensors (not embedded in the graph as a node and new graph not being created for each invocation of function with array of same signature even though different values). 2. a =b will be converted to tensorflow equivalent statement and become a part of the graph if it could be made a part of the graph if the right side could be converted to an equivalent tensor type. 3.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer explains, only `tf.` calls (operations) are transformed by a `tf.function`.

To understand why, you should think what it means to write `tf.print("msg")` in a python program. It says:

1. **Define** a Tensorflow operation (op for short) that does something. (It prints as side-effect, in this case, but the actual result is not important)
2. **Run**. This happens because eager execution is enabled by default in TF2.

Essentially, when you decorate with `tf.function`, all the ops you define are collected, and reused later. So, every istruction that doesn't define a Tensorflow Op can't be recorded by Tensorflow. The `+` sign does define an op implicitly, in you example, because `tf.function` converts `x` to a Tensor, then pass it to `f(x)`.

To answer to the most recent doubts:

1. Yes, numpy arrays, and other native types, are treated as tensors, because TF ops and functions (a `@tf.function` decorated def) first call `tf.convert_to_tensor` on their inputs.
2. No, `a=b` is not recorded because it simply copies the reference of a Tensor from one variable to the other. Assigments don't transform tensors.